# Excel: Find 2nd to last value in a range of columns

Tags: excel, indexing, get, excel-formula

I would like to get the second to last value from a range of cells in excel.

I can get the last non empty value just fine, like so:

```
=INDEX(DATA!T2:AE2,COUNT(DATA!T2:AE2))
```

But how do I get the value before this last non empty value?

I thought it would be a simple case of:

```
=INDEX(DATA!T2:AE2,COUNT(DATA!T2:AE2)-1)
```

but this subtracts the value.

Comment: If there are no blanks, your formula seems to work fine here.  Show your data and actual results.

Comment: There are blanks. Data is too large to share unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as,

```
=INDEX(Data!T2:AE2, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN(A:L)/(Data!T2:AE2<>""), 2))
```

Comment: this works, could you explain what's going on? I'm fairly new to excel.

Comment: Try the [Evaluate Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) command. Read about the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF).